# Error in VBA Code - Invalid Next control variable reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which returns an error: Invalid Next control variable reference. Can anybody point to where I am wrong and how do I Improvise? The code is to extract rows based on a certain key word from cell A2 onwards

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim DVariable As Date
    Dim RngFind As Range
    Dim MonthNo, YearNo As Integer
    Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date
    Dim PasteCell As Range
    Dim M As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    ws1.Name = "NEW"
    Sheets("Macro").Select
    For M = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Macro").Select
            With Sheets("By Trader")
    'loop column N until last cell with value (not entire column)
                For Each Cell In .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row)
                    If Cell.Value = M Then
             ' Copy>>Paste in 1-line (no need to use Select)
                    .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("NEW").Rows(Cell.Row)
                    End If
                Next
            End With
     Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A few notes: You should declare `ws1` as a worksheet `Dim ws1 As Worksheet`. You should try to avoid using `.Select` as is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). It doesn't seem like you need the `.Select` statements in this case. Have you tried specifying your `Next` statements like this: `Next Cell` and `Next M`? You should also declare `Cell` as a `Range`.

Comment: the shown code can't trigger the error you write about: update the post with the _real_ code or error

Comment: its the real code:(

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is not working. Cells works with numbers, so you should go for `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` or `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` Same issue on `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "N")`